# backbone fetch then render model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection that already filled with models and I need to update this collection with one more model and show it (model) on the page. So, following the docs, I get model from server in the view:

```
this.collection.fetch(
{
    add: true,
    data: FILTER + '&page=' + (CURRENT_PAGE + 1),
    success: function(response){}
});
```

But this new model doesn't show up on the page, but the collection gets new model. I suppose that some method of the collection has to be fired, but it does not.

Sorry in advance, newbie in Backbone)

The view:

```
    var EcoNatureCardInListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    className: 'nature-card-tr',
    template: $('#natureCardsListTR').html(),
    render: function(){
        var tmpl = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
        this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
var EcoNatureCardsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#nature-cards-wrapper'),
    events: {
        "click a.short-eco-entity": "showFullEcoNatureCard",
        "click #add-cards": "addCardsOnPage"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        $("#nature-cards-list").html("");
        this.collection = new EcoNatureCardCollection();
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(response){}
        });
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        this.collection.on('add', this.add, this);
    },
    render: function(){
        var that = this;
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
            that.renderEcoNatureCard(item);
        }, this);
        $(addCards).show();
        $("#total-objects").text(TOTAL_OBJECTS);
        $("#filtered-objects").text(FILTERED_OBJECTS);
        if (this.collection.length < 20){
            $(addCards).hide();
        }
    },
    renderEcoNatureCard: function(item){
        var ecoNatureCardInListView = new EcoNatureCardInListView({
            model: item
        });
        $('#nature-cards-list').append(ecoNatureCardInListView.render().el);
    },
    showFullEcoNatureCard: function(e){
        var _id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('value');
        var natureCard = ecoNatureCardsListView.collection.where({ _id: _id })[0];
        if (typeof(fullEcoNatureCardView) === 'undefined'){
            fullEcoNatureCardView = new FullEcoNatureCardView(natureCard);
        } else {
            fullEcoNatureCardView.initialize(natureCard);
        }
    },
    addCardsOnPage: function(){
        this.collection.fetch({
            add: true,
            data: FILTER + '&page=' + (CURRENT_PAGE + 1),
            success: function(response){}
        });
    },
    filterDocs: function(FILTER){
        $("#nature-cards-list").html("");
        //$(loading).show();
        this.collection.fetch({
            data: FILTER,
            success: function(response){}
        });
    }
});
```

P.S. version 0.9.2

Comment: Please post your view where you use this collection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that your view only subscribe to the "reset" event of the Collection, which is not triggered when you call fetch with the add:true option. In this case it will only trigger an "add" event, so you need to listen to that as well.
What I generally do is that I have

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
this.collection.on('add', this.renderEcoNatureCard, this);
```

In my view's initialization function, and the view's render function calls the add function for each model of the collection.

P.S.: with Backbone 0.9.2 I think that you have to use .on(...) as listenTo wasn't there yet.

Comment: You might also want to clear already rendered items, when rendering, or only render items that are new to the collection. Otherwise you might get the same items get rendered over and over again.

Comment: Good catch on the 0.9.2 version.

Comment: @David placed your two lines to init and render methods, but still doesn't work

Comment: Can you update your post to have a better idea of what the issue might be?

Comment: @pixelcdv Ok, just a sec.

Comment: Alright sorry, I hadn't seen the rest of your code, so I updated my reply to call renderEcoNatureCard instead of add. (I wrote this.add but this was supposed to be the function that renders and add a new Card view)

Answer (score 2):

You need to render when the collection is changed. I never used `reset` so I'm not sure when it's fired.

Change

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);`
```

to

```
this.listenTo(this.collection,'add remove',this.render);
```

Try not to use `on(..)` for Views. Otherwise you have to call `off(..)` when the View is removed. When you use `listenTo` the View will take care of removing events when it's destroyed.

**EDIT:**

You do not have to declare a local reference to `this` when using Underscore.js.

Change:

```
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
        that.renderEcoNatureCard(item);
    }, this);
```

To:

```
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
        this.renderEcoNatureCard(item);
    }, this);
```

When you use callbacks in Underscore.js the parameter after the function reference is the `context`. That is the object space the function will be executed in. You were always telling it to run the function using `this`.

Comment: listenTo doesn't work with 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listenTo'' error

Comment: Try adding the line to the initialize function.

Comment: @alexvassel could be a version issue. Is there a reason why you're using the older version?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini The project uses an old version. I am a new guy here) I think that it is a version issue too. Tried in the init function.

Comment: @alexvassel ah, the plight of the new guy. Just go to work wearing a t-shirt that says "WTF!" on it. It'll save you some time when you have meetings about old legacy source code.